# Modularization of Jasper reports: Pass data source to subreport without unnecessary db roundtrips?

Tags: jasper-reports, datasource, ireport, subreport

In this thread [how-to-pass-main-report-data-source-to-subreport-jasperreports](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8494036/1915920) it is stated that there may be **problems with subreports on reusing an existing master reports data source**.
It says the **subreport may close the datasource prematurely** (before other iterations calling the subreports may be processed).

It seems that this may be my problem because the report is always generated (without an error) ...

- **ok:**  **using the connection** from the master report (thus each time executing the query again: once for the master and additionally for each subreport call :-( )
- **wrong:**  **using the datasource** from the master report

  - likely a follow up problem: an empty page is attached then

I set up the `Data Source Expression`, `Parameters` and `Parameter Map Expression` as follows:

```
<group name="COUNTRY" isStartNewPage="true" isReprintHeaderOnEachPage="true">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{COUNTRY}]]></groupExpression>
    <groupHeader>
        <band height="84">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement uuid="92d7fc8c-9735-4dd1-ab0d-604d734bd659" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="-2" y="5" width="555" height="75"/>
                <parametersMapExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}]]></parametersMapExpression>
                <subreportParameter name="COUNTRY">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{COUNTRY}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport( $P{BASE_DIR} + "/reports/CITIES.jrxml"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </groupHeader>
</group>
```

I am using the latest (2013-11-06) Jaspersoft Studio Plugin 5.5.0.final (in Eclipse Kepler 4.3.1.M20130911/1000).

I want to use only one query executed once (against the database - since it is quite expensive) for the master report and a subreport that may be called arbitrary times for each group row/band. (So far this requirement and methodology seems quite plausible for many similar use cases to me. I explicitely do not want to avoid subreport functionality here because they offer the modularity and reusability I would like to utilize.)

The query has this nature (**where less than 100 rows are returned in total; a lot more complex and expensive ;-)** ):

```
query = "select country, city from cities"
```

The **proper** resulting report has this nature:

```
country: Germany, cities:
  Berlin
  Munich
  ...
country: Austria, cities:
  Insbruck
  Vienna
  Graz
  ...
...
```

The **wrong** result looks like this:

```
country: Germany, cities:
  Berlin
(additional empty page)
```

desired master report pseudo functionality:

```
ds = getDatasource()
ds.setQuery( query )
rs = ds.executeQuery()  // result set of master report

for country in getDistinctCountries( rs ) {
  println( "country: " + country + ", cities:" )
  subreport.process( country )
}
```

desired subreport pseudo functionality (taking over the datasource from the master report avoiding further database roundtrips):

```
subDs = getDatasource()
subDs.setQuery( query + " where country = " + reportParams[0] )
subRs = subDs.executeQuery()  // result set of subreport

for city in rs
  println( "  " + city )
```

I hope somebody could explain if I am missing something or if it is necessary (and how to do it) to clone ([JRResultSetDataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRResultSetDataSource.html) does not support it) such a datasource (or something similar).

Comment: here somebody said it's not (easily) possible and one should/could reuse the connection only (as I do now): http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/524231/datasource-some-subreports

Comment: here some ugly workarounds from 2004 are documented (basically cloning datasources with custom-written classes): http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/507017/nesting-subreports-nested-data-sources

Comment: another related query: http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/531580/subreports-parameter-question