# Passing collection to subreport in Jasper

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I create a simple report. I have the main report and a subReport.

I successfully pass a data source to the subreport so I can show my rows. Now what I'm trying to achieve is to pass a collection to the same subreport to create a chart. I add a parameter map in the main report linked to the subreport, type collection. Then in the subReport I add a parameter with  the same name type collection, but now I don't know how to access the data to create the chart. As text I add a simple string parameter and it works, but when collection kicks in I'm lost.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass main report data source to subreport (JasperReports)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490563/how-to-pass-main-report-data-source-to-subreport-jasperreports)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to create a chart, in the subReport, using data from the mainReport ... if that is your aim, so firstly try to create fields in the mainReport, once you have created the fields in the mainReport, so you can access those Fields in the subReport as you want...
To create a Fields (in other worlds, to add a fields), in the outline, Right Click on the 'Fields', then hit 'Dataset and Query', then add your fields from your data source or create your own, then hit ok ...

I hope it will help you...