# How to send column/fields to subreport as collection in jasper

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

So I've been able to make a second data source, pass down parameters, im all but ready, but I cant figure out how to send a collection of the field values in a column to the sub report. Ive tried setting a variable to the field value and sending that, I've tried sending the field directly.

I sort of assumed these wouldn't work because the data type is wrong, but i just don't know how to tell jasper that i want the fields as a collection.

Comment: May I ask your jasper or iReport version?

Comment: My JasperStudio version is 6.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass main report data source to subreport (JasperReports)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490563/how-to-pass-main-report-data-source-to-subreport-jasperreports)

Answer (score 0):

I use this in JasperSoft Studio 5.6.0 and it work fine :

```
<dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{subReportDataField})]]></dataSourceExpression>
```

Where "subReportDataBean" is a field like this :

```
<field name="subReportDataBean" class="java.util.List">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[subReportDataBean]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
```