# Creating Subreport with list of list

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I have a list of goals, each of which have another ArrayList in it. I want to have the details in the child ArrayList to be displayed using a subreport. I would like to have a subreport for each of the objects in the child ArrayList.

The issue I am facing is that, I can't seem to find a way to specify the ArrayListas data source for the subreport. When trying to create datasource, I can't select fields of the dataset on which the list is built, only the fields of the main report can be selected.

Is it possible to do this in jasper report? I am stuck with this for quite some time now.

Comment: Can you add some code that you tried?... like this the question is very "fussy", I can try to answer but I need to guess what you really like to do... How is your bean object (some code), what do you like to pass to the subreport?...ecc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass main report data source to subreport (JasperReports)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490563/how-to-pass-main-report-data-source-to-subreport-jasperreports)

Answer (score 4):

With information given this would be the answer.

**Main bean** (your goals?), containing `List` of other bean (`SubBean`).

```
public class Bean {
  private String var1;
  private List<SubBean> subBeans;
  public String getVar1() {
    return var1;
  }
  public void setVar1(String var1) {
    this.var1 = var1;
  }
  public List<SubBean> getSubBeans() {
    return subBeans;
  }
  public void setSubBeans(List<SubBean> subBean) {
    this.subBeans = subBean;
  }
}
```

**Sub bean**

```
public class SubBean {
  private String var2;
  public SubBean(String var2){
    this.var2 = var2;
  }
  public String getVar2() {
    return var2;
  }
  public void setVar2(String var2) {
    this.var2 = var2;
  }
}
```

**How to pass the SubBean List to a subreport.**

1. You need the field subBeans in you main report.

   ```
   <field name="subBeans" class="java.util.List"/>
   ```
2. I suggest that you pass the location of the .jasper file as a parameter (Note jasper report needs absolute path) es. in main report

   ```
   <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
   ```

and in java pass it (in example sub folder "jasper" in working directory is the location of the subreport.jasper)

```
paramMap.put("SUBREPORT_DIR", new File("jasper").getAbsolutePath() + File.separator);
```

3. Now just call your subreport (needs to be complied into .jasper) from main report like this.

   ```
   <subreport>
     <reportElement x="105" y="4" width="400" height="100"/>
     <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{subBeans})]]></dataSourceExpression>
     <subreportExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "subreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
   </subreport>
   ```

Hence:

I'm creating a new [JRDataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRDataSource.html) for the sub report passing the `List` of  `SubBean` in the current `Bean`

```
new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{subBeans})
```

indicating the absolute location of the compiled subreport.jasper

```
$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "subreport.jasper"
```

so now in your subreport you can use the field: `var2` of the `SubBean`, just define it like this in the subreport.jrxml

```
<field name="var2" class="java.lang.String"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Essentially I have a parent list component in ireport. Inside that I have the subreport. The subBeans field is part of the dataset of the list component and not the main report. I understand its possible to use main report fields to develop datasource expressions, my problem is I want to use a field from my dataset. Is that possible?

Comment: "I want to use a field from my dataset", in the main report??, .. or the main Bean in the subreport?. Try to edit question with your Beans and some jrxml