# Send nested object to Jaspersoft iReport

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I try to use Jaspersoft iReport to create Report from my POJO and export it to PDF.

My POJO looks like this:

```
class Topic {
    String topicName
    int topicPoints;
    DateRange dateRange;
    List<Post> posts;
}

class DateRange {
    LocalDate begin;
    LocalDate end;
}

class Post {
    String postName;
    int postPoints;
}
```

I found solution with JRBeanCollectionDataSource, so I created list with one element (my POJO).

```
ArrayList<Topic> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(topic);
JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanColDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(list);
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, beanColDataSource);
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "C:/jasper/test.pdf");
```

I have no problems with exporing simple data like Strings, Integers etc.

e.g. this exports fine.

```
class Topic {
    String topicName
    Integer topicPoints;
}
```

With just:
Drag & Drop fields topicName (with `"java.lang.String"`) and `topicPoints` (with `"java.lang.Integer"`)

But how can I put on my reports nested fields inside dateRange or inside posts?

I see there is field class like `java.lang.Object` or `java.util.List`, but how can I define fields inside this Object or List?

My ideal solution would've create report like:

[image: My example]

UPDATE:

```
class Topic {
    String topicName
    int topicPoints;
    DateRange dateRange;
    List<Post> posts;
}

class DateRange {
    LocalDate begin;
    LocalDate end;
}

class Post {
    String postName;
    int postPoints;
    List<User> users;
}

class User {
    String userName;
    int userPoints;
}
```

And what in case when it will be even more nested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `jrxml` you can define the structured fields (for nested objects) like this:

```
<field name="dateRange" class="my.package.DateRange">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="dateRange"/>
</field>
<field name="posts" class="java.util.List">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="posts"/>
</field>
```

And then use values from nested objects like `$F{dateRange}.getBegin()`.

---

But in your case it seems that you have always one topic and iterate posts for it. Then it would be better to:

- pass topic as a parameter: `parameters.put("topic", topic)`
- create `DataSource` for posts: `JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanColDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(topic.getPosts())`
- define parameter `topic` in the report: `<parameter name="topic" class="my.package.Topic"/>`
- in report render topic values using parameter expression: `$P{topic}.getTopicName()`
- define fields for Post in the report
- in report render post values using fields (i.e. `$F{postName}`) in the detail band - JasperReport will automatically iterate all posts and render them

**Update** (*to answer the updated part of the question*): To render values of type `Collection` (`List`) you can use subreports - see here: [Creating Subreport within list in iReport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33475934/creating-subreport-within-list-in-ireport) It means that you will create subreport to render user values.

Or you can use `table` to render users with `subDataSet` created from users list:

```
<jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
    <datasetRun subDataset="usersDataSet">
        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{users})]]></dataSourceExpression>
    </datasetRun>
    ...
</jr:table>
```

And you must also define the `subDataset` for the table:

```
<subDataset name="usersDataSet">
    <field name="userName" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[userName]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="userPoints" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[userPoints]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
</subDataset>
```

Comment: Thanks, let me digest it, and if everything will be fine I'll accept answer ASAP.

Comment: Can you explain me what is this class="my.package.Topic"? Is this a path in my project to this folder or what? I think I do not have connected iReport and project together I do report separetly. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: It is full `Topic` class name with it's package (`my.package.Topic` is only example - I don't know your correct package ;-)). You can create jar with all those POJO classes and add it into iReport class path by **Tools** --> **Options** --> **Classpath** --> **Add JAR**

Comment: You can also create factory class with static method which will create `Collection<Post>` with some mock data and include that class also in the jar with POJO classes. In iReport you can then register it as a JavaBean DataSource and use it for testing (better preview of the report). For more details you can look here for example: https://community.jaspersoft.com/blog/how-set-javabean-set-datasource-ireports-along-working-sample

Comment: seems like I understand much more now. If you could update your answer with idea what to do if it will be double nested list. I'll obiously accept answer after that. :)

Comment: Answer updated - I hope it will help to you.